# Interpretieren "wie"/"als"?

Tags: conjunction

In einer kontrastiven Analyse, in der der Übersetzer einen konditionalen Nebensatz durch einen kausalen Nebensatz wiedergibt, möchte ich folgenden Satz schreiben, zweifle aber an der Wahl der Konjunktion:

> … der deutsche Übersetzer interpretiert den italienischen
>   Konditionalsatz **als/wie** einen Kausalsatz.

Ich neige zu *als*, aber hundertprozentig bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Comment: Beides ist hier möglich, **etwas interpretieren als** ist jedoch eine feste Phrase für das Gemeinte und deshalb zu bevorzugen.

Comment: @Janka Ganz genau. Wenn es bereits eine feststehende Wendung gibt, fällt es auf, wenn jemand sie vermeidet, und erweckt den Eindruck, er hätte gerade diese Bedeutung *nicht* gemeint. Dadurch bewegen sich die üblichen Interpretationen der beiden Alternativen auseinander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Verben *sehen, beschreiben, wahrnehmen, deuten, interpretieren* (und möglicherweise noch einige andere), geben, zumindest wenn sie mit *als* oder *wie* zusammen verwendet werden, eine vergleichende Wahrnehmung wieder.

> Ohne Brille sehe ich die Katze nur **als** dunklen Fleck.
> Ohne Brille sehe ich die Katze nur **als** einen dunklen Fleck.
> Ohne Brille sehe ich die Katze nur **wie** einen dunklen Fleck.

Wie man sieht, sind beide Konjunktionen, jeweils gefolgt von einer adverbialen Bestimmung, möglich, wobei *wie* zwingend ein Determinativ (z.B. einen Artikel oder ein Pronomen) verlangt, während das Determinativ im Fall von *als* optional ist.

Der Unterscheid in der Bedeutung ist sehr subtil und in den meisten Fällen vernachlässigbar:

- > Ohne Brille sehe ich die Katze nur **als** (einen) dunklen Fleck.

  Ich weiß, dass ich eine Katze betrachte, aber in meinem Gehirn entsteht *eine andere* Wahrnehmung, nämlich die eines dunklen Flecks. (Vergleich des tatsächlichen Objekts mit der daraus entstandenen Wahrnehmung.)
- > Ohne Brille sehe ich die Katze nur **wie** einen dunklen Fleck.

  Wenn ich eine Katze und einen dunklen Fleck betrachte, erfahre ich *dieselbe* Wahrnehmung. (Vergleich zweier gleicher Wahrnehmungen, die von verschiedenen Objekten herrühren.)

---

Derselbe subtile Unterschied tritt in deinem Beispiel auf:

- > Der deutsche Übersetzer interpretiert den italienischen Konditionalsatz **als** (einen) Kausalsatz.

  Der deutsche Übersetzer erkennt, dass es sich um einen italienischen Konditionalsatz handelt, und er behandelt ihn so, als wäre er ein Kausalsatz. (Vergleich der tatsächlich vorliegenden Satzart mit ihrer Interpretation.)
- > Der deutsche Übersetzer interpretiert den italienischen Konditionalsatz **wie** einen Kausalsatz.

  Der deutsche Übersetzer behandelt italienische Konditionalsätze und Kauslasätze gleich. (Vergleich zweier gleicher Interpretationen, die aber auf verschiedene Satzarten zurückgehen.)

Answer (score 1):

Hubert's Antwort ist per se erstmal richtig, aber zur Verständlichkeit nochmal wie ich es erklären würde:

> … der deutsche Übersetzer interpretiert den italienischen Konditionalsatz als einen Kausalsatz.

Der Übersetzer tut so, als wäre der italienische Konditionalsatz ein Kausalsatz.

> … der deutsche Übersetzer interpretiert den italienischen Konditionalsatz wie einen Kausalsatz.

Er interpretiert den Satz so, wie er einen Kausalsatz interpretieren würde.